# Minimalist propositional logic negation axiom

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What is an axiom schema for [minimalist propositional logic](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Johansson%27s_Minimal_Logic) that characterizes negation ($\lnot$), but, does so without introducing the $\bot$ symbol to the language?

I thought that maybe $$\dfrac{X, X \to \bot}{\bot}$$ could be replaced with $A \to X \to \lnot X \to \lnot A$ , but that doesn't seem to work for really small expressions like trying to prove $(B \to \lnot \lnot B)$....or maybe it does and I am missing an obvious proof?

Comment: Not clear... I think that [Minimal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_logic) has $\bot$ and the def of $\lnot A$ as $A \to \bot$, but has **no** rule for $\bot$.

Comment: This means that we can have "derived" rules like $A, A \to \bot \vdash \bot$, by $\to$-elim, as well as $\bot \vdash \lnot A$, by $\to$-intro.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Yes that's right, normally ML is just positive partial fragment of propositional logic plus a $\bot$ symbol added to the language that follows all the rules for propositional variables except for substitution (or you could just think of it as a zero arity operator).  I was trying to find an alternative where $\lnot$ is introduced to the language instead, and rules are added to fully characterize it.

Comment: So minimalist logic with a $\{\implies, \lnot, \text{Propositional Variables}\}$ signature instead of having $\{\implies, \bot, \text{Propositional Variables}\}$ as a signature

Comment: See Sara Negri & Jan von Plato, [Structural Proof Theory (2008)](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZvACGkn9138C&pg=PA12), page 12 : "The above system of introduction and elimination rules for $\land, \lor \to$, together with the rule of assumption by which an assumption can be introduced at any stage in a derivation, is the system of natural deduction for *minimal propositional logic*. If we add rule $\bot \text E$ it we have a system of natural deduction rules for *intuitionistic propositional logic*."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That author is also using $\lnot P$ as an abbreviation for $P \to \bot$, exactly the same as the link in my question.  I'm looking for minimalist characterization of $\lnot$ that does not use $\bot$ at all.

Comment: To do so, you must have rules for $\lnot$. What rules ? How to replace $A, \lnot A \vdash \bot$ and $A \ldots \bot \vdash \lnot A$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes that is exactly my question.  And I would consider the system complete if every minimalist proposition which doesn't contain any $\bot$ after all translations of $A \to \bot$ to $\lnot A$ is provable.  In other words, all valid minimalist propositions involving only variables, $\implies$, and $\bot$.  So there is no need to prove the sequents you referenced because they cannot be rewritten only in terms of negation.

Comment: IMO, if the minimal log has no rules for $\bot$, your version (without it) will have no rules for $\lnot A$. This means that the negation sign will not "pop up" in any proof if not already there in a subformula of the assumtions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes such a system does show the propogative nature of $\lnot$ more clearly.  In addition to propogating from assumptions, it can also come from a subformula, such as $\lnot_2 (A \land \lnot_1 A)$, where the $\lnot_2$ "comes from" the $\lnot_1$.  Anyway, maybe this question is more difficult than I originally thought it would be, I may have to just work it out myself.